# Viewing log for errors in Whitebox GAT?

Tags: whitebox-gat, log

I don't know how to open up the log in Whitebox GAT so I can view and fix errors with running tools.

I tried to run the IDW tool for LiDAR data (inputting all necessary parameters), then an error message popped up saying "An error has occurred during operation. See log file for details." I I looked everywhere in the Whitebox options, under services, view, etc. but couldn't find a way to pull up the log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where you unzipped the Whitebox application, there is a `logs` sub folder with 3 .xml files that can be opened in a browser.

```
HelpLog0_0.xml
LauncherLog0_0.xml
WhiteboxLog0_0.xml <- this is probably the one with tool related errors
```

As of Whitebox GAT 3.3 'Glasgow' there isn't an option to view logs within Whitebox GAT itself.

Consider using the "Help > New Feature Request" tool to request anything you feel is missing.